# How to create roles in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I would like to create a aws_iam_role with terraform but after running `terraform apply`I get the following error message:
`aws_iam_role.role: Error Updating IAM Role (edb_eb_role) Assume Role Policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource`

That is my policy:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
name = "edb_eb_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "logs:*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

What did I wrong? I also tried to do it only with Principals but then I get the message that "Principals" is also not prohibited?

Comment: AssumeRole can't have the policy directly. You need to do this using aws_iam_role_policy_attachment step.

Comment: provide a link to your reference of policy json. Will post the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assume_role_policy don't accept the aws policy json files.** So the above code is not working.
 For detailed explanation of assume_role_policy in aws_iam_role, see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628380/terraform-assume-role-policy-similar-but-slightly-different-than-standard-ia).

Update the code as shown below and execute.

```
variable policy_arn{
    default = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaRole"
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "edb_role" {
name = "edb_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": ["ec2.amazonaws.com" ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}


resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
    role       = "${aws_iam_role.edb_role.name}"
    policy_arn = "${var.policy_arn}"
}

output "role" {
  value = "${aws_iam_role.edb_role.name}"
}
```

Here, we are using the AWSLambdaRole Policy present in Policies section of IAM.

- Add multiple policies to a role using [aws_iam_role_policy_attach](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy_attachment.html)
- Use the default policies provided by aws as show above. Else to create a new policy, see the docs [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy.html)